# Recursion for strings: Is this correct

Tags: recursion

My question is pretty straightforward:
Give a recursive definition for the set of all strings of a’s and b’s, where all the strings are of even length.

I have attempted to solve the above question and I was wondering if you could tell me if my solution is correct or on the right track.

Updated solution

Base:  ∈ S

Recursion: if s ∈ S

aas ∈  S

abs ∈  S

bas ∈  S

bbs ∈  S

Comment: Base case: $\epsilon \in S$.

Comment: Sorry but could you help me understand how I would solve this if  ∈ ? In that case, would it be s "if s∈, s∈ s∈" Is that not too broad since I have to shown a and b would be an element first?

Comment: No, @lhf is saying that your base case should be that $\varepsilon$ (the empty string) is in $S$ (since it has even length, $0$, and vacuously contains only $a$'s and $b$'s).  The recursive step is already correct.  Unlike with your current base case, you can now show that $ba$, $aa$, and $bb$ (and strings starting with those pairs) belong to $S$.

Comment: Thank you both, it makes sense now. I've updated by recursion step as well!

Comment: Not sure your recursion step is correct anymore... now it only generates strings with equal numbers of $a$'s and $b$'s.  (For instance, now $bb\not\in S$.)

Comment: Sorry, when I said I updated it, I meant on my actual assignment. I updated here as well if you would like to double check!